# Any way to invoke this Windows volume up/down window through Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, winapi, volume

[image]

Any way to actually call this Windows volume window through Python?

I know that I can use pycaw to change the volume itself, I've done that already. I need help to call this one.

Comment: I don't remember the name of this media overlay off the top of my head but I believe it is a WinRT API.

Comment: *"Any way to actually call this Windows volume window"* - What is that supposed to mean? You cannot *"call"* a window. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @IInspectable Overlay is what I meant, it's 5AM here.

Comment: This overlay appears when I try to change my volume with keyboard function shortcuts, so is there any way I can do the same thing from Python directly? What I mean is to ask what API it is in?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/system-media-transport-controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pywin32 you can send key board input for `VK_VOLUME_UP`/`VK_VOLUME_DOWN`, the key message will bring up that annoying window, example

```
import win32con
import win32api
import time

win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_VOLUME_UP, 0)
win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_VOLUME_UP, 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP)
time.sleep(1) #sleep is just to see the effect, it's not required here

win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_VOLUME_DOWN, 0)
win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_VOLUME_DOWN, 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP)
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Now that I actually think about it, it must be annoying to have that overlay popup everytime I change the volume lol. Thanks though!

Comment: By the way, I added `sleep` to see the effect better, you can remove sleep from actual code.

Comment: The problem with this is of course that if the volume is at 100% then doing this will lower the volume! You should go down then up instead.

Comment: @Andres, it doesn't loop back, it's the same as pressing the volume up/down key. Or is it different in your system?